# Question on dividing by zero

Tags: functions

I currently work on a problem where I consider a model which requires calculation of the term

$$\frac{1}{U'(0)}$$

with $U'(x)=x^{-0.5}$.

Therefore $U'(0)$ is undefined.

However, $\frac{1}{U'(x)}=x^{0.5}$ is defined for $x=0$ so I get

$$\frac{1}{U'(0)}=0^{0.5}=0$$

Is this conclusion allowed (even though $U'(0)$ is undefined)?

Comment: Can you just get away with taking the limit of $1/U'(0)$ as $x$ approaches $0$?

Comment: Wouldn't it be more relevant that your model uses a term $Y'(x)=x^{0.5}$ instead of $1/U'$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  The domain of $1/U'(x)$ is everything in the domain of $U'(x)$ such that $U'(x) \ne 0$.  But $0$ is not in the domain of $U'(x)$.

While it's true that $1/U'(x) = x^{0.5}$, the problem is actually *getting* to $x^{0.5}$.  Consider:
$$\frac1{U'(x)} = \frac1{\frac1{x^{0.5}}} = x^{0.5}$$

That second equality won't work if $x=0$ because the middle expression is undefined if $x=0$.

Comment: I did a numerical test and found that you are correct, I cannot apply it that way.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on your model.  In some cases, you know the final result is defined and continuous (for reasons based on the model).  If that is true, then having a few points where the calculation is undefined will not matter.